# Select count from three tables Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, count, inner-join

I am building a job website and one of my challenge is like this. I have three tables:

1. locationlist (field: id, title)
2. jobpost (field: id, job_title, job_desc,......)
3. jobpostlocation (field: id, locationlist_id, jobpost_id)

Notice:

- locationlist table store list of locations (eg. location 1, location 2, location 3,...)
- jobpost table is to post job announcement, which employers can tick more than one locations stored in jobpostlocation table.

Could you tell me how to list all items from locationlist table with count next to each location item like below?

### JOBS BY LOCATION:

- Location 1 (89)
- Location 2 (27)
- Location 3 (0)
- Location 4 (48)
- Location 5 (0)
- Location 6 (0)
- Location N (....)

My current code:

```
    $q = DB::table('locationlists')
        ->leftJoin('jobpostlocations', 'locationlists.id', '=', 'jobpostlocations.location_id')
        ->leftJoin('jobposts', 'jobposts.id', '=', 'jobpostlocations.jobpost_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Your requirement is not so clear. You say you have three tables but you want to display from location_list. Please post some code too to help you out

Comment: I update my question and hope it makes enough sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this setting a user defined variable using `SET` keyword

For Example :

```
SET @count=0;  #create a variable for counter
SELECT location @count:=@count+1, * FROM location_list; 
#Increment variable by adding 1 to it.
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you give me the complete Laravel code (controller and view)?

Comment: Firstly, you didn't post any code. Besides, you didn't say anything about PHP-Laravel. All it says from your post is displaying items from table "location_list"

Comment: You should see the title of my post saying Laravel 5

Comment: Have you posted any of the code plz? With little to no information nobody can help you. More information better for you